# Durandal modal in modal issue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal, knockout-mvc, durandal-2.0

I'm trying to call custom modal inside modal and catch the retrieving data. So I'm receiving second modal's data inside first modal, but the first modal's buttons crash for parent viewmodel and does not send data, even can't click on buttons, no effect. In case if you don't open second modal, firsts buttons work correctly. I mean "save" and "cancel" buttons, what are default in Durandal modal.

Is this my code issue or it's impossible to do on that way in Durandal 2.0?

If it's possible in Durandal, I'll go to put some code here.

Comment: Yes, it's quite simple to have a modal dialog open another modal dialog, _Ad infinitum_. I have done it in my projects. You only need to bind an event on the parent modal to open the child modal. And you can easily pass data from the child to the parent by using promises.

Comment: Yes Brett, I did that, but when I close second modal, then I can't close first modal, buttons crash.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: We need a code example of your problem to assist further.